# Is it possible to recover day's worth of queries from sql server log file?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, recovery, transaction-log

I lost all data entered and edited in my system yesterday, and my ISP has announced to me that last night's backup is corrupt and cannot be recovered.

Is there any way to access the database's log file to try and recover the database to the point immediately before the day's data was deleted?  I'm using SQL Server 2012 Standard Edition.

I've tried this (which I found in another question on this site):

```
SELECT deqs.last_execution_time AS [Time], dest.TEXT AS [Query]
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS deqs
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(deqs.sql_handle) AS dest
ORDER BY deqs.last_execution_time DESC
```

but I'm only getting queries since this morning.

I'd be immensely grateful for any help.

Comment: Log files only contain the *physical* changes to the database, not the queries that affected those changes. Do you have readable log backups available?

Comment: My most recent non-corrupt backup is missing yesterday's data - that's the problem I'm trying to find a solution for, if there's one to be found.

Comment: In particular, I have a single table which is append only that, if I could recover, I would be heads and shoulders above where I am currently.

Comment: What recovery model is your database in?

Comment: Recovery model is "Simple".

Comment: Running `SELECT * FROM ::fn_dblog(null, null)`, the first row returned has a `Checkpoint Begin` value of `2012/06/22 10:10:58:520'.  Would I be correct in assuming that the log was truncated at 10:10 this morning?

Comment: Yep. If you try to use a 3rd-party tool to analyze the log file, it will have to be capable of reading inactive portions of the log file... and any log wrap-around will have overwritten the transactions from yesterday.

Comment: ApexSQL Log can read SQL Server 2012 t-logs and undo each operation. They have a 14 day free trial, you can download it from their site. Good luck!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your only real chance is using a 3rd-party log analyzer tool, and even that may not work. `SIMPLE` recovery truncates the log when a `CHECKPOINT` process occurs, which is highly likely to have happened at this point.

Also, if losing the entire set of changes between backups is unacceptable, either back up more frequently in `SIMPLE` (if your database is small), or switch to `FULL` and take log backups as well to get point-in-time recovery ability. Corrupt backups notwithstanding.

Comment: @Remi: You're welcome. Sorry for your data loss. The best bet at this point is to set up a backup strategy that better meets your needs. And also, make sure to test the backups you do take.

Comment: Right, you should have a restore strategy, not a backup strategy. If you create backups and stuff them on some disk somewhere, but don't validate that you can actually restore from them, don't bother taking backups in the first place. They're not guaranteed unless you've tested them.

Answer (score 1):

There's a free tool that reads transaction logs, but it's only for SQL Server 2000: http://www.red-gate.com/products/dba/sql-log-rescue/
I think Apex has something, but it's not free

Answer (score 0):

Odds are your database is in simple recovery mode as most hosting companies keep the databases in simple recovery mode to make the backup and restore process easier to automate.  This means that there is no transaction log that you can use to recover your data from.  Pretty much your only option here will be to rebuild the missing data, and hopefully find the bug that caused the data to be deleted.